# Power BI Cumulative Total Drops to 0

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a cumulative total calculation like bellow,

```
Cumulative Total = CALCULATE(COUNT(Pace[SUBCASE_NUMBER]), FILTER(ALL(Pace[TRT_DAYS]), Pace[TRT_DAYS] <= MAX(Pace[TRT_DAYS])))
```

However when I plot this, the line drops for TRT_DAYS where there are not any SUBCASE_NUMBER's like bellow.

[image]

How do i make this a continuous line?

Comment: Can't recreate. [Edit] your question to to include representative sample data (or preferably a sample PBIX file)

Comment: @Olly the problem seems to only occur when using a filter populated with values from another table2 which then has a relationship back to the original data set 1. I changed the filter values to use the ones in the original data set 1 but not ideal. Any idea on how to get around this? This now means i cant use my table2 values as a filter which filters all my imported datasets.